# set a message in drupal

Tags: drupal

I need to do one of two things in Drupal

1. have the ability to set a info message to a specific user to view next time they login. This message would show up in the standard $messages variable. I looked to see if drupal_set_message() had the capabilities but didn't find it
2. run a function everytime a page is loaded that would then look for some info that would then cause the drupal_set_message to be sent

I prefer the second option, if anyone has suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would place code in hook_init(). Most of Drupal has been loaded and it is available on every page load.

Within that, you could query for a list of messages form the database and funnel them into drupal_set_message(). The $messages variable is stored in the session, so you need to call drupal_set_message() at the time you actually want to show the message.

Storing the need to present the message is a different challenge, and depends on how you determine a message needs to be set. If it is based simply on elapsed time, you can skip custom coding and go straight to Rules--defining triggers and actions based on user login date.

If it is a more dynamic messaging scheme, where you need to notify users of events which have happened in their absence, you might use write code based around the [Message](http://drupal.org/project/message) module or something like it, which would allow you to record messages to the database, and then query for anything dated since the user's last login. In fact, I like that idea, it bears further thought...

A more specific question would help in recommending more targeted solutions.

Answer (score 1):

as basically a page is a node in drupal, you should implement the [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6). For user connection, use the [hook_user](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_user/6) (with the login operation).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hook_boot` for run a function everytime a page is loaded.